# Simple algebra question

Tags: algebra

Am I missing something here? This does not resolve to True.

```
Clear[x,y]

$Assumptions={x>0,y>0}

FullSimplify[(Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]) == Sqrt[x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y]]]
```

Comment: `Simplify[Reduce[{(Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]) == Sqrt[x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y]], 
   x > 0 && y > 0}], {x > 0, y > 0}]`

Comment: I think this  is limitation in `Simplify` because `Reduce[(Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]) - Sqrt[x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y]] == 0, Reals]` gives `y >= 0 && x >= 0`, therefore `Simplify` with this assumption _should_ give `True` but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, 
  Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y] == Sqrt[x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y]]], PositiveReals]
```

> True